# restart application and redirec to a specific form in C#

Tags: c#, logout

I am developing a Windows Application using C#.

It has 4 forms.

1. Splash Screen,
2. login Screen,
3. Main Menu &
4. User Details form which
   display inside the Main Menu form,

and there is a button name as "Log-out". i tried using `Application.restart()` method inside the log-out button, but it will load the splash screen before the login screen. 
My Concern is how to display the login screen page when i click on the log-out button.

Note :

```
userdetails ud = new userdetails();
ud.ShowDialog();
```

code used to display the user details form inside the main Menu form.

Thank you
Ishan

Comment: Depends a fair bit on how you structured your login, but, normally, IMHO, you would just invalidate the log in is valid and reshow the login screen, and on success of that open next form, on fail either try again or quit

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a security manager class that holds the user credentials / security token, any request that needs a security check then has to go through your security manager. on this class you have an event that fires when a security request is made when there are no details on record,

eg

```
public class SecurityMonitor
{
    public string Username{get;set;}
    public string Password{get;set;}
    public event LoginEventHandler LoginRequired;
    public bool CheckSecurity()
    {
        if(Username==null)
        {
            LoginRequired?.Invoke(this,new LoginEventArg());
            //wait logic here
        }    
        return CheckAccess();
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        Username= null;
        Password= null;
    }
}
```

then in your main form you have

```
SecurityMonitor security = new SecurityMonitor();
security.LoginRequired += (s,e)=> ud.ShowDialog();
```

this will then redirect the users to the log in screen when ever credentials are required with out having to restart the app